# SQLite Random sub query result

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, random

I have 2 SQLite tables, table_a and table_b.  Table A contains a list of categories and Table B contains a list of words.

I'm trying to get all categories from table_a and a random word from table_b for each category.  The below query allows me to get 1 result per category that has the lowest id in table_b.

```
    SELECT table_a.category_id, table_a.category, subQuery.word, subQuery.word_category, subQuery.word_id
    FROM table_a,
    (SELECT *
      FROM table_b
      GROUP BY category_id
      HAVING MIN(word_id)
    ) subQuery
WHERE subQuery.category_id = table_a.category_id;
```

Is there a way to return 1 random result from table_b for each category in table_a instead of the value with the lowest id?

I'm not really having much luck finding an answer online.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your subquery doesn't make sense. You `GROUP BY category_id` and `SELECT *`. This would be invalid, if `category_id` were not unique in the table. So, as it is unique obviously, you can remove `GROUP BY category_id` altogether from the query, it has no effect. Then, `HAVING MIN(word_id)` translates to `HAVING MIN(word_id) = TRUE`, as a condition must be a boolean expression. `MIN(word_id)` is just a number or string. SQLite converts this to a boolean (0 = false, other values = true). This means if `min(word_id) = 0`, then you get no row; if it isn't, you get all rows.

Comment: If the GROUP BY clause is removed then the query returns multiple records from table_b, however when it is in the query I get one result for each category however it returns the lowest id for each of the categories.  This is close to what I need, I just need a random result from table_b per category instead of the result with the lowest id.

Comment: This is weird. SQL does not allow you to `group by something` and `select *` if that `something` is not unique in the table. SQLite violates this rule. The query is invalid and SQLite should reject it. It is unfortunate that it doesn't. This is the cost for having a very slimlined DBMS it seems. That you happen to get the minimum values is a coincidence based on how SQLite cheats here internally. Don't rely on this. Understand why your query is invalid and avoid such queries in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function to pick one row per category:

```
select
  c.category_id, c.category,
  w.word, w.word_category, w.word_id
from categories c
left join
(
  select
    word, word_category, word_id, category_id,
    row_number() over (partition by category_id order by random()) as rn
  from words
) w on w.category_id = c.category_id and w.rn = 1
order by c.category_id;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=bbbe8541adf2d4f62883b2a1c36aaa41

### Update

You say that the query does not work in SQLite 3.8. We can only suspect a bug here, because we see it works in SQLite 3.27.

Here is another approach that may work for you. I am selecting a random word ID with each category using a `LIMIT` subquery. Then I join the word data.

```
select c.category_id, c.category, w.word, w.word_category, w.word_id
from
(
  select
    c.category_id, c.category,
    (
      select word_id
      from words w
      where w.category_id = c.category_id
      order by random()
      limit 1
    ) as word_id
  from categories c
) c
join words w on w.word_id = c.word_id
order by c.category_id;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7630068aa3ba71e70b7a6bddd83047dc

Comment: Unfortunately this query seems to return an error, I've tried a few queries similar to this one but without any luck.

Comment: If the query returns an error, you should tell me *which* error you are getting. And if you had looked at the error message and tried to understand it, you might have found the error yourself. Anyway, I found the error now. I forgot to select the `category_id` in the subquery. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Cool so it works in SQLite 3.27, for some reason when I run it in 3.8 it returns a syntax error.  it looks like there is an  error somewhere in 'row_number() over (partition by category_id order by random()) as rn'

Comment: Again, if there is an error, tell me which error. What does the error message say exactly? Anyway, this is strange. The query is pure standard SQL, except for the random function, which should still be present in SQLite 3.8. I have no explanation. Can you run the subquery standalone? Do you get the same error message?

Comment: Yeah sorry, forgot to include the message.  it says could not prepare statement (1 near "(": syntax error), the sub query doesn't run on its own.  If I run the query but remove ',
    row_number() over (partition by category_id order by random()) as rn' and 'and w.rn = 1' then it returns results.  So it looks like 3.8 doesn't like something about this part of the query.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what may be wrong. The query should work in 3.8 as much as in 3.27 of course. Maybe you introduced a typo somewhere by mistake?

Comment: I doubt there will be, I copied your schema from the dbfiddle into my SQLite database and ran the same queries to be sure it was identical.  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Okay. This may be a bug then. I've added an alternative to my answer.